# Sharepoint 2013 Online Auto Increment Based on Another Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

For some reason we're attempting to use SharePoint for end-to-end job lifecycle management for a construction company (VP has decided that SharePoint must be a better solution than my hand-rolled PHP/MySQL job lifecycle implementation that has been used successfully for over a year). As best I can tell SharePoint was never designed for this, but I have zero experience with it so I could be totally wrong. Problem number 1 of 16 million or so:

The company assigns each job a job number, the format for these is xx-yzzz. XX is a job prefix, 51-64 that determines the type of job (this is related to a Job Prefix list). Y is the last digit of the current year, and ZZZ needs to be auto-incremented from the previous job number with the same XX prefix. Using a relational database this is easy, SELECT jobNumber FROM tblJobNumbers WHERE jobPrefix = "51" ORDER BY jobNumber DESC LIMIT 1; and then add 1 to that result (job number xx-y000 is an internal number, so this won't break on January first).

My understanding from every bit of Google-fu I could muster is that this would be relatively trivial (other than learning ASP, but whatever, know one and know them all right?) if I was running Sharepoint Server and had a .NET IDE. Unfortunately I have neither of these things (also, no InfoPath, but if that's what it takes I might buy it with my own money at this point). Is there a way to do this between Sharepoint 2013 Online and SP2013 Designer on the desktop?

Bonus question: can I then concatenate jobPrefix and JobNumber in another column so it is searchable by job number as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to compare to the previous job number with the same XX prefix, but to answer your bonus question, you can download SharePoint Designer Workflow String Actions WSP from here: http://spdwfstringactions.codeplex.com/ I saved the file in c:\deploy\

To deploy this solution, run SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator:

> Add-SPSolution c:\deploy\.wsp
>
> Install-SPSolution -Identity SPWorkflowStringActions.wsp -GACDeployment
>   Make sure SPDWorkflowStringActions assembly is in C:\Windows\assembly.

Open SharePoint Designer. Now in workflow actions you will have a String Actions group that you can you for string manipulations (create a workflow that starts when a new item is created, copy values from jobPrefix and JobNumber to another column and use the string manipulation actions to get what you need). I hope it'll help!

Comment: I appreciate the answer, unfortunately I'm forced to work with Sharepoint Online, so I don't believe I am able to run SP Management Shell. I did, however, figure out that you can do this with calculated cells which is good enough for now.